# How to convert '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02�U��j�0\x10E��\n' data gotten from google userinfo api to an object using nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, buffer, google-apis-explorer

I am implementing google OAuth and i am recieving the access_token and and id_token quite alright.

After sending a request to google's userinfo endpoint as shown in this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgIkK.png)
I am recieving a success from goole with this data type on the response data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7r7H.png)

A few months ago when i implemented this on a seperat project i got back an object and not i am getting this, whatevery it is.
Can anyone point me where i can research or convert this to an object using javascript?

I am expecting an Object and i have tried using the global Buffer method available on Nodejs and i keep getting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E8s1.png)

Comment: needs to add 'Accept-Encoding' a correct format  in [header of Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564610/axios-response-doesnt-show-the-data/74567789#74567789)

Comment: You are welcome, your vote me, will give me encourage.